# O que significa o -u de um no curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Gostaria de saber o que significa o `-u` na requisição em `curl`. sei q o `-h` significa `header` e o `-d` informa se vou mandar `POST GET ou PUT`.

Comment: Se não me engano é um alias para `--user`. É utilizado para autenticações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O -u é um alias para --user 
Se você simplesmente especificar o nome do usuário, o curl solicitará uma senha.

Manual do comando com exemplos: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#